# AppleScript to download file

Tags: applescript

I need to write an AppleScript to open Safari and go to https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/ to download the first csv file

Comment: This is not a question, it is outsourcing a task or homework.

Comment: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing your work for you by providing you with a code snippet to accomplish this task, I will instead provide you with a great resource. Cube MG has a bunch of tutorials that are really helpful for interacting with web page elements via Safari. Check it out here: http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/

There are other ways that you could approach something like this such as using the command line but that is a bit more advanced. Check out Cube MG and see what you can learn!

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties ¬
        {URL:"https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/"}

    repeat
        if the front document's source contains "What are CSV files?" then ¬
            exit repeat

        delay 0.5
    end repeat

    tell the front document to set CSVfiles to ¬
        do JavaScript "Array.from(document.links,
                                  x=>x.href)
                            .filter(x=>x.indexOf('.csv')!=-1);" 
end tell
```

This gets you the links to all the CSV files.  To extract the first one, use `item 1 of CSVfiles`.

---

**NB.**  Don't forget to enable *Allow JavaScript from Apple Events* in *Developer* menu (a hidden menu, made visible through *Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar*)

Comment: A few things about your answer: 1. Copy and pasting the code as is into Script Editor errors on compile, `Expected expression but found “tell”.`. Had to change `set CSVfiles to tell the front document to ¬` to `tell the front document to set CSVfiles to ¬` for it to work. 2. `repeat while the name of front document = "Untitled"` is unreliable as the `name of document 1` can change before the page is completely loaded and `{}` can/will be returned for the JavaScript command. 3. Allow JavaScript from Apple Events on the hidden Developer menu in Safari needs to be checked, which isn't by default.